# how to remove <p> , </p> and <br /> which are obtained by parsing JSON response

Tags: java, android

I got JSON response from server parsing json response i got content which contains `<p> </p>` and `<br />` how to replace all with blank or white space?

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was this handy **How to Format** box. Worth a read. There was also a nice preview area underneath where you were typing.

Comment: We can't *usefully* answer this question without much more information. What does the content *actually* look like? Is JSON really relevant, or have you already deserialized it into an object graph by the time you're dealing with it? What does your code working with this look like?

Comment: @vyb See my answer for simple solution, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the `replace` function? Or is that too easy..

For example:

```
json = json.replace("<br />", " ");
json = json.replace("<p>", " ");
json = json.replace("</p>", " ");
```

I don't know how your json looks like before this replacement. But it could of course be possible that you have `&lt;br /&gt;` instead of `<br />`. In that case you have to of course change the replacement tags.

It could also be possible you will have to use regexes. I don't really know off the top of my head how this is done, but you can Google this

Comment: i am using this code but its not removing content = content.replace("<p>", "");

Comment: That is maybe just a problem with encoding?

Comment: Can you give us a result of what you have before the replacement and what you have after it?

Comment: but i used content = content.replace("<br />", " ");

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will solve your problem.

```
String str = "<p>Your String</p>";
Spanned sp = Html.fromHtml(str);
```

And see below link for more information.

[How to preserve HTML in formatted strings](http://blog.andromo.com/2011/how-to-preserve-html-in-formatted-strings/)

Answer (score 0):

Try `mystring.replace("<b>", "");`

Also, you can replace `<br />` with `\n`.